# How to select next class in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to remove disabled attribute from input text box, after click on "Click here for editing" and want to add class ".make-editable" on input text box, but from the next input box.

For example :- If we click on first heading ("Click here for editing")then its next text box should be editable and want to add class "make-editable"

I tried below code, but its not working.

```js
$('.click-here-for-editing').click(function(){
    
   $(this).next()('.edit').addClass('make-editable').removeAttr('disabled');
  
    });
```

```css
input:disabled {background: #fff; border: none}
input.edit{ border: none;font-size: 26px; color: #444444;}
input.make-editable{ border: solid 1px #ccc; padding:5px 10px;}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="click-here-for-editing">Click here for editing</span>
  <h1><input type="text"  value="Dummy Text 1"  disabled class="edit"></h1>
  </div>
 <div>
  <span class="click-here-for-editing">Click here for editing</span>
  <h1><input type="text"  value="Dummy Text 2"  disabled class="edit"></h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
  $(this).next('h1').find('.edit').addClass('make-editable').removeAttr('disabled');
```

`Next` element after span is `h1` so you should use this `.next('h1')` and in `h1` find element with class `.edit` (`.find('.edit')`)

[Example](http://jsbin.com/sayebu/1/edit?js,output)